# Create classes that grab youtube queries and display information using Python

Tags: python

I want to use the urllib module to send HTTP requests and grab data.  I can get the data by using the urlopen() function, but not really sure how to incorporate it into classes. I really need help with the query class to move forward.  From the query I need to pull
• Top Rated
• Top Favorites
• Most Viewed
• Most Recent
• Most Discussed

My issue is, I can't parse the XML document to retrieve this data.  I also don't know how to use classes to do it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib #this allows the programm to sen HTTP requests and to read the responses.

class Query: 
    '''performs the actual HTTP requests and initial parsing to build the Video-
    objects from the response.  It will also calculate the following information
    based on the video and user results.  '''

    def __init__(self, feed_id, max_results): 
        '''Takes as input the type of query (feed_id) and the maximum number of 
        results (max_results) that the query should obtain. The correct HTTP 
        request must be constructed and submitted. The results are converted 
        into Video objects, which are stored within this class.
        '''

        self.feed = feed_id
        self.max = max_results


        top_rated = urllib.urlopen("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated")
        results_str = top_rated.read()
        splittedlist = results_str.split('<entry')
        top_rated.close()


    def __str__(self):
        ''' prints out the information on each video and Youtube user. '''
        pass


class Video:
    pass


class User:
    pass



#main function:  This handles all the user inputs and stuff.
def main():
    useinput = raw_input('''Welcome to the YouTube text-based query application.
You can select a popular feed to perform a query on and view statistical 
information about the related videos and users.

1) today
2) this week
3) this month 
4) since youtube started

Please select a time(or 'Q' to quit):''')
    secondinput = raw_input("\n1) Top Rated\n2) Top Favorited\n3) Most Viewed\n4) Most Recent\n5) Most     Discussed\n\nPlease select a feed (or 'Q' to quit):")
    thirdinput = raw_input("Enter the maximum number of results to obtain:")

main()

toplist = []
top_rated = urllib.urlopen("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated")
result_str = top_rated.read()
top_rated.close()
splittedlist = result_str.split('<entry')
results_str = top_rated.read()



x=splittedlist[1].find('title')#find the title index
splittedlist[1][x: x+75]#string around the title (/ marks the end of the title)
w=splittedlist[1][x: x+75].find(">")#gives you the start index
z=splittedlist[1][x: x+75].find("<")#gives you the end index
titles = splittedlist[1][x: x+75][w+1:z]#gives you the title!!!!
toplist.append(titles)
print toplist
```

Comment: You should make your question more specific. "I've got coder's block" is probably not a good SO question. What kind of queries do you want to make? How are they related? What do you want your classes to represent?

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific.  Each class basically borrows the data obtained in the Queries class.  How do I use that class to parse the data at the points that I mentioned.  The url that I provided under top_rated provides the query for all the top rated videos.  That can be edited to specific times and number of videos.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your challenge is parsing XML.

```
results_str = top_rated.read()
splittedlist = results_str.split('<entry')
```

And I see you are using string functions to parse XML. Such functions based on finite automata (regular languages) are NOT suited for parsing context-free languages such as XML. Expect it to break very easily.

For more reasons, please refer   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

**Solution**: consider using an XML parser like elementree. It comes with Python and allows you to browse the XML tree pythonically. http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm

Your may come up with code like:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
..
results_str = top_rated.read()
root = ET.fromstring(results_str)
for node in root:
    print node
```

---

> I also don't know how to use classes to do it.

Don't be in a rush to create classes :-)

In the above example, you are importing a module, not importing a class and instantiating/initializing it, like you do for Java. Python has powerful primitive types (dictionaries, lists) and considers modules as objects: so (IMO) you can go easy on classes.

You use classes to organize stuff, not because your teacher has indoctrinated you "classes are good. Lets have lots of them".

Comment: I have posted how I get the name of the first video.  We basically have to use the classes that I posted.  How can I use the my parsing method to get the names of all the videos from the api.  How can I get it to search for every 'title' that comes up, instead of stopping at the first.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to use the Query class to communicate with the API.

```
def __init__(self, feed_id, max_results, time):
       qs = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/"+feed_id+"?max-    results="+str(max_results)+"&time=" + time
       self.feed_id = feed_id
       self.max_results = max_results
       wo = urllib.urlopen(qs)
       result_str = wo.read()
       wo.close()
```

Comment: XML basically stores all the relevant information inbetween the "<entry".  You split your file there.  From there it's just a matter of list indexes.  Just use the .find() function to find the list index that you want to start at and then do the same for where you want to end at.  This will give you the relevant information. I did all this under the video class.